# Audio Frequency Separation In Python

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, fft

I'm working on a nerd project for fun.
The project is analog video recorded onto an audio cassette.
The challenge lies in the very limited bandwidth.
I have a method to record color video at 24fps along with mono audio.
I got the video stuff working but need some help with the audio.
Here is the signal I have to work with:

Note: using YUV color space

Left channel:
Sync Pulses &
Y (luma) data

Right channel:
U & V (chroma) data
mixed with
Mono audio (Amplitude Modulated at 14kHz)

I'm not sure how to separate the color data from the audio.
I've looked into FFT with numpy a bit but am not fully understanding it.

Basically what I need is a band filter to separate 13990Hz - 14010Hz (to account for wow and flutter)

Comment: Scipy has filter design functions. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html

Comment: Won't work.  The AM modulated carrier will have a bandwidth of up to twice the highest audio frequency in your mono audio.  Much more than the 20 Hz bandwidth filter you specify (which can be implement by FFT overlap add/save fast convolution).

Comment: The AM carrier is 14kHz therefore the max audio frequency response would be 7kHz if I understand correctly. And this is good enough to understand speech and such.

Comment: I got it working with the scipy functions but I must've screwed something else up because the video is just random noise :| I'll post the solution once I get all the bugs sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a little test code that shows how this works.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math as mt
from scipy.signal import butter, sosfilt, lfilter

def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
        nyq = 0.5 * fs
        low = lowcut / nyq
        high = highcut / nyq
        sos = butter(order, [low, high], analog=False, btype='band', output='sos')
        return sos

def bandpass(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
        sos = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
        y = sosfilt(sos, data)
        return y

def bandstop(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq

    i, u = butter(order, [low, high], btype='bandstop')
    y = lfilter(i, u, data)
    return y

# Modulation & Bandpass Test

# note that the data is just test data and isn't actual audio or color data

Fs = 192000 # rate
f = 14000 # carrier frequency (Hz)
sample = 192000 # total length

x = np.arange(sample)
signal = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * 1000 * x / Fs)) # audio
noise = 0.5*(np.sin(2 * np.pi * 10000 * x / Fs)) # color data

y = [] # combined AM audio and color data

for t in range(0, sample, 1):
    amp = (signal[t] + 1) / 2
    sine = amp * (mt.sin(2*mt.pi * f * t / Fs))
    y.append((sine+noise[t])/2)

# y is raw signal
w = bandpass(y, 1600, 1800, 24000, order=1) # only AM audio signal
v = bandstop(y, 1450, 1950, 24000, order=6) # Rest of the signal
# Note: lowered the sample rate input for the filters (and frequencies accordingly) 
# since it didn't like 192khz

# The color data does get impacted by the bandstop filter but this is 
# mostly not noticable as the YUV color space is used meaning
# the color resolution can be reduced drastically without noticable effect
    
plt.plot(y)
plt.plot(w)
plt.plot(v)
plt.xlabel('sample')
plt.ylabel('amplitude')
plt.show()
```

If you want to check out the full code along with a wav of the signal and an example video of the output here's a link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18ogpK4n43d_Q0tjdmlm2uIRZBIrRu01y?usp=sharing